# Is there a way to add entity in draftjs that are unbreakable?

Tags: entity, draftjs

I'm using the draftjs editor. I have a decorator that detects some pieces of text by regex and generate a homemade component. This one is calling an API and returning the result by replacing the initial piece of text with the result of the API.

And i would like to have this result as a non breakable, non editable entity, and i don't know how to do it.

Here is the function i use to replace value

```
/**
   * Replace text in editor
   *
   * @param {Object} editorState  - State of the editor
   * @param {string} search       - Search value
   * @param {string} replaceValue - replacement value
   *
   * @returns {Object} Returns the new editorState with link removed
   */
  static replace(editorState, search, replaceValue) {

    if (typeof search === 'undefined' || search === null) {
      return editorState;
    }

    const regex = new RegExp(escapeStringRegexp(search), 'g');
    const blockMap = editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockMap();
    const selectionsToReplace = [];
    blockMap.forEach((contentBlock) => (
      findWithRegex(regex, contentBlock, (start, end) => {
        const blockKey = contentBlock.getKey();
        const blockSelection = SelectionState
          .createEmpty(blockKey)
          .merge({
            anchorOffset: start,
            focusOffset: end,
          });

        selectionsToReplace.push(blockSelection)
      })
    ));

    let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

    selectionsToReplace.forEach(selectionState => {
      contentState = Modifier.replaceText(contentState, selectionState, replaceValue)
    });

    return draftEditorState.push(editorState, contentState);
  }
```

What i would like is that the result can be moved or removed as a global part and can not be changed.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Draftjs' [`entities`](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-entities#mutability). Say if you apply an entity with `IMMUTABLE`, it'll be treated as uneditable and if you try to delete part of the word the whole thing will delete.

Here is an official [draftjs example using entities](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/entity/entity.html) but that uses pre-marked segments. I think in your case it would be as simple as doing something like this inside `findWithRegex` (haven't tested this so this might be way off -- just trying to get the idea across):

```
let newContentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

findWithRegex(regex, contentBlock, (start, end) => {
  const blockKey = contentBlock.getKey();
  const blockSelection = SelectionState
    .createEmpty(blockKey)
    .set("anchorOffset", start)
    .set("focusOffset", end);

  const searchEntity = content.createEntity(
    "SEARCH", // type
    "MUTABLE", // mutability <--
  );
  const entityKey = content.getLastCreatedEntityKey();

  newContentState = Modifier.applyEntity(searchEntity, blockSelection, entityKey);
})

return EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, "apply-search-styling");
```